# MVC - how to define reusable paragraph I could use on any page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paragraph

I am beginning with MVC ASP.NET and stumbled upon a problem. There is a paragraph (some 5 sentences) I would like to use on several of my child pages. This text **changes quite often so I would like to have it defined on 1 place** so I dont have to update like 10 pages when it changes again.

Problem is, that I dont know how to do it. I was thinking about using **CSS** (which should be used for styling, not text) or **sections** (doesnt work, as each child page needs its own sections defined).

Could someone advise me the most optimal and "correct" way to achieve this? I would like **to define this paragraph at one place and then "call it" from the child page** without need to use the database. Which approach should I choose?

Thank you

Comment: Use partial views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one **partial view** and call in your main view:

```
@Html.Partial("YourPartialViewName", Model) //if you have some dynamic data pass in model
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize that I can call partial views also from child pages, not only from master page